# Terminology: facet versus face in polytope

Tags: geometry

In a [polytope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytope), what are the difference and relation between facet and face? How are they defined respectively?
Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually **facet** is synonymous with **maximal face**. Or in other words, if the polytope is of dimension $d$, the facets are the faces of dimension $d-1$, or codimension $1$.

A **face** is just a common name for $\emptyset$, vertices, edges, and so on. Often one says that a $k$-dimensional face is called an "**$n$-face**". Usually one also says that the whole polytope is a face also (this is to ensure that intersection of faces is also a face). The mathematical definition of a face varies in the literature (as the Wikipedia article mentions) - but often one says that a face of a polytope is a subset of the polytope maximizing some linear functional (though this definition is not very intuitive...)

Comment: (1) What are faces of a polytope then? (2) How would you call a 2-dimensinal face? Thanks, +1!

Comment: @Tim: I've added some more on faces also.

Comment: Thanks! (1) Is there a name for  a 2-dimensinal face? (2) Also what is "some linear functional"?

Comment: I see that a 2D face is called a face!